# How to make a NULL Comparison on If condition compared with JSON Response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm Trying to make a comparison between the Data that comes from a Webservice (JSON RESPONSE) and compare it on the Objective C class I've the following code.

I must mention that on viewdidload I set the next_page_url to null otherwise i get an error. Change it like shown below:

```
next_page_url = @"null";
```

This is the response:

```
{
    "count": 16, 
    "next": "http://api.domain.com/user-search/?page=2&subject=a", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Guillermo Davila", 
            "nick": "gdavila", 
            "avatar_s": "http://domain.com/images/image_9994449333.jpg", 
            "user_rate": "$5/h", 
            "id": 3, 
            "subjects": "Web Development and 1 other subject", 
            "bio": "I am a programmer"
        }]
}
```

This is the Controller.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if (next_page_url == (id)[NSNull null]) {

        NSLog(@"NEXT_PAGE_URL: IS NULL URL-->%@",next_page_url);
        return myObject.count;


    } else {

        NSLog(@"NEXT_PAGE_URL: NOT NULL +1 NEXT_PAGE_URL-->%@",next_page_url);
        return myObject.count+1;


    }


}
```

What this does is, When it loads it shows a Loading Indicator by default because it always says that next_page_url is not null.

Comment: And what does the log say?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, or where.  But try `next_page_url = @null;` (no quotes).

Comment: (You probably don't understand the distinction between an NSNull object vs the `null` pointer value.  It's hard to tell which you're trying to set/test for.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check like this...And change your key instead of "next_page_url"

```
if ((NSNull*)next_page_url != [NSNull null] && next_page_url != NULL)
     NSLog(@"This value is not contain with nulll value");
else
     NSLog(@"This value is contain with nulll value");
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this next_page_url = @"null"; to this: next_page_url = null;

Comment: I get - Use of undeclared identifier 'null'

Comment: self UserTableViewController * 0x109f708d0 0x0000000109f708d0
next_page_url NSString * nil 0x0000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever compare objects with ==
It compares the pointers address and they may not be same.
Also you should understand the difference between `NULL`, `Nil`, `nil` and `[NSNull null]`:

`NULL` is used in C, do not use it in Objective-c.
`Nil` is an empty class.
`nil` means that there is no instance, pointer to nothing
`[NSNull null]` is used to represent empty object en collections. You can't insert nil into `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, thus you use it.

So if you want to check for nil, if there is actually any instance do

```
if (next_page_url)  {
```

If you need to check if you got `[NSNull null]` object use

> if ([next_page_url isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

This code is wrong:

```
 if (next_page_url == (id)[NSNull null]) {
```

Comment: I changed it, but now it crashes when it loads.

Comment: Remember the API returns a null string.

Comment: its not "" it is null

Comment: Actually, the two statements are equivalent, since NSNull is a singleton class -- there is only ever one of them.

Comment: @eddwinpaz What API returns null? Can you be more clear? From the code you provided this is not clear.